How to Resolve Internal Server Error (500) When Running React SSR Application on IIS with iisnode
I'm encountering an issue with my React SSR (Server-Side Rendering) application deployed on an IIS server using iisnode. The application runs fine locally with SSR, but when I try to access it through the server, I get a 500 Internal Server Error.
Here is relevant part of the code
package.json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build-server": "webpack --config webpack.server.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "ssr": "npm run build && npm run build-server && node build-server/main.js"
  },

webpack.server.js
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  entry: './server/server.js', // Ensure this path is correct
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build-server'),
    filename: 'main.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              '@babel/preset-env',
              '@babel/preset-react'
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  }
};


web.config
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="build-server/main.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="DynamicContent">
                    <match url="/*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="build-server/main.js" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <iisnode loggingEnabled="true"/> 
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>



error when browsing site url


https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ You can switch to HttpPlatformHandler.

I think the problem is related to your port settings, I can reproduce your problem like this(not match the node.js server port and process.env.PORT is not configured to pass to IIS):

Please modify this to
PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

This should resolve your issue. I referred to this article and deploy success with iisnode:


that doesn't seem to be the issue, i tried port 3001 and 3002, still the problem presists.

If this is the case, I'm not sure what other causes there are, you may need to set system.webServer/iisnode/@loggingEnabled as true to get the logs and analyze them.
